# Volume of off-center cylindrical hole in Sphere

Tags: calculus

$S$ is a sphere of radius $2$, centered at origin. A cylindrical hole of radius $1$, centered at $(1,0)$ is drilled through $S$.

How much materials from $S$ was removed?

**Attempt**

$z = \sqrt{4 - x^2 - y^2}$ is the equation of the top half of the sphere.

Let $R$ be the region bounded by the equation of the intersection between the cylindrical hole and x-y plane.

Then, integrate the top half of the sphere over this region:

$$\int \int_R \sqrt{4 - x^2 - y^2} dx dy$$

Comment: Might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani%27s_curve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the volume of that hole cut from the sphere, by finding one fourth of that volume first. As you noted, the area is as follows:

[image]

The correct volume is $$V=4\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{r=2\cos(\theta)} \sqrt{4-r^2}rdrd\theta$$= 16/9 (3 π - 4) ≈ 9.64405

Comment: Thanks! Especially the diagram!

Comment: The diagram is wonderful! How'd you make it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a complicated question. The "cap" volume is what is difficult to evaluate. As Jack mentioned, it leads to an elliptical integral. However, since Sphere Radius = 2*eccentricity = 2*hole radius, you fall in to a special case where all of the elliptical integrals disappear. This is also known as "Viviani's Curve". This link has the formulas for the volume of the remaianing sphere:
http://diynovice.wordpress.com/2012/12/02/hole-in-sphere/

Answer (score 1):

By translating the domain of integration and switching to polar coordinates I get:

$$ V=4\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\pi}\rho\,\sqrt{3-\rho^2-2\rho\cos\theta}\,d\theta\,d\rho,$$

that leads to an elliptic integral.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559814/is-the-proof-i-am-using-enough-for-the-system-of-equation/2559931?  $\\$ Dear teacher, can you look my problem, if you have a few minutes. Thank you so much.